# Problem of difference in between matrix multiplication done by * and by components by components by hand (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, matrix, multiplication, floating-accuracy

I have a problem with the accuracy of matrix multiplication on Matlab. I will explain this with an example.
Let

```
 A=[0.1256, 0.25789; 0.00018, 0.68741];
B=[0.1578, 0.24471; 0.12801, 0.99701];
s=0;
while s<100
    for i=1:2
        for j=1:2
    A(i,j)=A(i,j)+0.0125;
    B(i,j)=B(i,j)+0.2470;
        end
    end
    D=A*B;
    d11=A(1,1)*B(1,1)+A(1,2)*B(1,2);
    d12=A(1,1)*B(1,2)+A(1,2)*B(2,2);    
    d21=A(2,1)*B(1,1)+A(2,2)*B(1,2);
    d22=A(2,1)*B(2,1)+A(2,2)*B(2,2);
    DD=[d11, d12; d21, d22];
    s=s+1;
end
```

I have an algorithm where the values of matrix A and B components are upgraded at each iteration. In this algorithm, there is also a formula that involves the definition of a matrix as the product of the upgraded A and B.

**My problem is** if I define at each iteration these new matrix components by components executing by hand the matrix multiplication I would obtain a result slight different with respect to the case I define this new matrix by execution of matrix multiplication done by Matlab by "*" and not components by components by me.
The final result is:

```
DD=[71,8082684418998,   73,0622074848998;
79,4048550050998,   80,8251256858998]
and
D=[71,6322976788998 73,0622074848998
79,1787592580998    80,9710216918998]
```

**Can it be possible?** Thanks in advance

Comment: It's a nice effort to provide an "example" to explain your question but to be really useful your example should also include **numerical values**, so people can reproduce the behavior you are trying to fix or achieve.

Comment: @rinkert I intend $C=A*B$ and by hand I intend: $c11=a*e+b*g;$ $c12=a*f+b*h$, $c21=c*e+d*g$, $c22=c*f+d*h$ and then $C=[c11, c12; c21, c22]$.

Comment: then just create the matrix `A` and `B`, and do `C=A*B`. Like Hoki said, add an example with minimal code to reproduce your problem to illustrate why this is not working for you.

Comment: I have added my code and the result, now I hope you could help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has not to do with numerical accuracy, but your manual matrix multiplication is wrong. This would be the correct version:

```
d11=A(1,1)*B(1,1)+A(1,2)*B(2,1);
d12=A(1,1)*B(1,2)+A(1,2)*B(2,2);    
d21=A(2,1)*B(1,1)+A(2,2)*B(2,1);
d22=A(2,1)*B(1,2)+A(2,2)*B(2,2);
```

But you see that it is easy to make mistakes in this manual matrix multiplication, so best to just do `A*B`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! But also with this correction for instance at the iteration 7 I have: D=[1.043469763900000,   1.362134194900000;
   1.604450243099999  , 2.285467301899999]

  DD= [1.043469763900000 ,  1.362134194900000;
   1.604450243099999  , 2.285467301899998]

Comment: Looking at d22 and dd22 they are not exactly equal...this is what I wanted to say in my question!

Comment: aha, now you are looking at floating point accuracy, the difference is of the order 1e-16, which is the limit of double precision. See [Accuracy of Floating-Point Data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html#f2-98690). This is expected, and most likely is not an issue for your application.

Comment: Anyway which one of the two procedures is preferable?

Comment: Go for the Matlab matrix multiplication, as you can see it is easy to make mistakes when implementing this manually. Since MATLAB uses BLAS to do linear algebra, `A*B` is more efficient than the manually implemented matrix multiplication.